# Hover state not working after multiple animations

Tags: css, animation, sass

I'm a little stumped here.

This hover state transform worked when I had one animation, now that I've added a second it stops working?

```
.right-bird {
  height: 58px;
  position: relative;
  top: -26px;
  left: -80px;
  opacity: .8;
  -webkit-animation: bird-from-right 1.9s linear, jiggy 4s ease 2.5s forwards;
  z-index: 50;
  max-width: 100%;
  &:hover {
  -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  } 
}
```

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: I think I'd be able to help if you show it as a fiddle !

Comment: Not the greatest fiddle but you get the point. http://jsfiddle.net/87LRt/

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your animation does works.

But: You're using `rotate` in the `jiggy` animation and in the `hover` state. In this case, the :hover rotate could --*on hover*-- replace the animation.

Btw, for exemplifying with Sass and CSS animations (cross-browser) you should put [your code in a CodePen](http://codepen.io/Volker_E/pen/mzhBk/) and not in a jsfiddle. At Codepen you've got a Sass compiler and [autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer) included, otherwise debugging your code gets more complicated.